# How to tell where a particular software is coming from

Tags: windows, virus

In the University repair shop I work for, we see a lot of the same viruses/spyware/adware/ransomware in a lot of cases.

Is there any way we can trace back to where a file or software package originated from in order to advise customers away from that location, whether that be on the Internet or a file share of some sort?

Comment: No; it's not possible even if it were the links are long dead trust me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: The problem exists between the keyboard and chair]

*If you trace it all the way back you will find that the problem exists between the keyboard and chair*

--

And the actual answer is **No**, unless you have ridiculous logging setup on the machine (prior to infection).